# shiny_output comparison results in html format

Tags: r, html-table, shiny, compare

Want to write an app to dynamically compare diffrent versions of xlsx-files using shiny and comparedf packages.

There was a problem with output of the comparison results in html format.

How to fix it? It is possible to output html with htmlTable package?

```
library(shiny)
library(compareDF)
library(htmlTable)

    ui <- navbarPage("Compare_app",
                      tabPanel("Compare relults",
                              sidebarLayout(
                                sidebarPanel(
                                  fileInput(inputId = "old_file", 
                                            label = "Chose old file", 
                                            accept = c(".xlsx")),
                                  fileInput(inputId = "new_file", 
                                            label = "Chose new file", 
                                            accept = c(".xlsx")),
                                  selectInput(inputId = "group_cols",
                                              label = "Group by:",
                                              choices = "",
                                              selected = NULL,
                                              multiple = TRUE)
                                  ),
                                mainPanel(
                                  mainPanel(
                                    htmlOutput(outputId = "compare_html")
                                  ) 
                                  )
                                )
                              )
                     )

    server <- function(input, output, session) {
old_file <- reactive({
  old_file_tmp <- read_excel(req(input$old_file$datapath), col_names = TRUE)
}) 

new_file <- reactive({
  old_file_tmp <- read_excel(req(input$new_file$datapath), col_names = TRUE)
}) 

observeEvent(old_file(), {
  updateSelectInput(session, "group_cols", choices = names(old_file()))

})

output$compare_html <- renderUI({
  vec <- unlist(strsplit(input$group_cols, ","))

  compare_result_tmp <- compareDF::compare_df(df_new = new_file(), df_old = old_file(), group_col = vec)

  compare_html <- compare_result_tmp$html_output
})
)
    # Run the application
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be trivially implemented by using the native shiny command -

```
  compare_html <- shiny::HTML(compare_result_tmp$html_output)
```

This should give output in the expected format